# What's the syntax for ORDERBY in VB.NET's LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, distinct, sql-order-by

I'm new to Linq, what's the syntax for order by in VB?

```
Dim cxt As New datContext
Dim qry = (From lst In cxt.zipcodes _
              Select lst.state).Distinct

    qry = qry.OrderBy()
```

my simple SQL statement will be like this:

```
Select distinct state from zipcodes
order by State
```

Comment: Can you accept an answer if one of the ones below helped?

Answer (score 38):

```
qry = qry.OrderBy(Function(obj) obj.PropertyToSortBy)
```

Answer (score 16):

Alternative syntax for your query (cleaner IMO):

```
Dim qry = From lst In cxt.zipcodes _
          Select lst.state Distinct _
          Order By state
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cxt As New datContext

Dim qry = (From lst In cxt.zipcodes OrderBy lst.state).Distinct.tolist

Dim statelst = qry.Select(Function(o) o.state).ToList
```