# How to restrict sort function to affect original array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I had used array.sort function to sorting an array, but this function not return new array but affected older.

To keep an original array, I create new array manualy, but sort function just affected both new array and original

```
Dim newardata = ardata
array.sort(newardata)
```

What should i do to keep that original array, thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Then study [Value Types and Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types)

Comment: Yes, it is an efficient in-place sort.  Consider the Linq [OrderBy() extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910762/whats-the-syntax-for-orderby-in-vb-nets-linq) to create a new collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating a new array in your code. Try [cloning the array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim newardata = ardata.Clone()
array.sort(newardata)
```

You could also try [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx).